# How to fix 'Aws S3 upload failed. Access Denied, region: null, statusCode: 403' on NodeJs

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I have an Amazon S3 bucket and I want to upload a file on Node.Js but when I start to process that were failed. I did simplify my problem but havent find solution. How can I solve this problem?

`"Access Denied\",\"code\":\"AccessDenied\",\"region\":null,\"time\":\"2019-04-10T09:20:45.047Z\",\"requestId\":\"6C1FE10BE8AC2E7E\",\"extendedRequestId\":\"reqId=\",\"statusCode\":403,\"retryable\":false,`

I give full access on amazon. / I added bucket on s3 object. / Checked keys and region. Non of them give me a solution

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');
let awsS3 = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: 'myAccessKeyId',
  secretAccessKey: 'random/sskjskjsk',
  region: 'us-west-1',
});

let params = {
  Bucket: 'mybucket',
  Key: 'testFile.png',
  Body: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/test.png')
};

awsS3.putObject(params, function (err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
  } else {
    console.log('AWS S3 upload successful!');
  }
});
```

Comment: Try with `aws-cli` through your console. You can read how it works here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/it_it/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html and how to install it on your OS - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, but how the cli would be solve my problem? I mean what would it change my situation?

Comment: With cli you could find if you can access s3 with credentials you provide. Because 403 error could be in two cases: wrong credentials or wrong permissions. You say that permissions is OK. Which leads us to credentials issue